# Zope browser page permission

Tags: security, browser, zope

I have a browser:page setup in Zope, and I have:
`permission="zope2.Public"`

My question is what should I change this to in order to allow only Plone administrators access, and/or logged in (non-administrators) access to this page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Zope, you control access to views via permissions, but to permit someone to access a given permission, you must grant such permissions to a role.

Anyone in the Plone administrators group has been granted the `Manager` role (on Plone 4.2 that'll [change to the `SiteAdmin` role](http://dev.plone.org/plone/ticket/10878)) generally have access to most permissions. There is also the automatic `Authenticated` role, which is given to anyone that has been authenticated (has logged in). The latter doesn't have many default permissions though.

Permissions are generally named after the action you want to permit. If your view's goal is to manage some aspect of your Plone portal, then the `cmf.ManagePortal` permission is probably what you want. You can check [the full list of default permissions](http://docs.plone.org/old-reference-manuals/plone_3_theming/buildingblocks/components/componentparts/permissions.html) if you need another one.

There is some [excellent documentation on how security works in Plone](https://plone.org/documentation/kb/understanding-permissions), which includes information on how to define new permissions too, and how to assign existing permissions to roles.

Answer (score 2):

permission="cmf.ManagePortal"

This setting is about *permissions* not about *roles*.